# Is there a RIP (Routing Information Protocol) Client for Mac OS X El Capitan?

Tags: macos, mac, vpn, routing

As a Windows support guy, I have recently tried setting a Mac up to access our work and clients' VPNs. We use Mikrotik Routers with RIP enabled to publish the routes for the multiple remote subnets to VPN clients. On Windows I just enabled the "RIP Listener" feature and punch a hole through the host firewall for port 520 UDP, and it works.

The searches I've done indicate that "routed" used to work on earlier OS X but no more.

Comment: Wow, still using RIP?

Comment: The use of RIP is historically based on the native availability of the RIP listener on Windows clients, as mentioned in the question, The Mikrotik routers will also do OSPF, BFD and BGP. If I can get the Mac to listen to announcements on any of those protocols that will still answer my question.

Comment: Why doesn't your VPN server (or whatever default gateway you give your VPN clients) know how to route to the remote subnets?

Comment: It does, but I don't want to set my remote VPN gateway as the default gateway, I want a "split tunnel". I need the VPN server to tell my client exactly which subnets should be forwarded on the VPN so that general Internet traffic is not forwarded to the VPN.

Answer (score -1):

Not natively, but you can install a routing daemon like Quagga or Bird from homebrew.  I'd say OSPF is the easiest answer here, if you absolutely require an answer like this.

Comment: I no longer use that Mac, but thanks for the answer - I'll leave it here for the record.